# How do you create either GUI or Forms in C++?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

How do you create either GUO or Forms (MFC) in C++? I am a beginner so it would be great if you reply in simplest form as possible.

Comment: Already answered here on SO - search for win32 console application. (Sorry, I'm on mobile so I can't grab a link for you at the moment.)

Answer (score 0):

In VS2010 there are two main kind of C++ template projects to generate very-simple executables:

1. **Console project** - this will generate a black-window console project with the main() function ready. This is not intended to do GUI-job and thus just shows a black console where you can easily write with `cout / printf` streams or functions (more on Console apps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875011.aspx)
2. **Win32 project** - this is intended to do graphic work (e.g. create a GUI) by creating text controls, buttons and all that windows stuff. (more on Win32 Windows apps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384845.aspx)

To immediately get you started, if you create a Win32 Windows project (NOT a console one) and you compile it, you should immediately see something like a blank window.

Another template that should be present on your VS2010 copy is a "MFC application", although this requires a bit of MFC knowledge to work with, but that will also suffice if you intend to see the structure of such a project.

If you intend to easily create GUI applications in C++ however, you might want to take a look at [Qt framework](http://qt-project.org/) or MFC classes.

Comment: Not really two types of projects. It's just a linker option that sets a flag in the PE header. This option can easily be changed in Project Properties. VS does have two separate *template* projects so I know what you mean, but this answer might mislead someone into thinking they need to recreate their project when all they really need is a linker setting.

Comment: I already fixed it. To generate simple executables I see no other way. MFC might be simple to use but it's definitely not easy to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different libraries that you can use for native GUIs. However, I would recommend against writing a GUI; if you want to present a UI, then, instead, it would be a good idea to embed an HTTP server in your application and simply print out the URL on localhost at which the server is running.

The advantage to this approach is that you can then use standard HTML, CSS, JavaScript for the UI rather than using platform-specific GUI frameworks/controls. And, furthermore, if you decided to allow the application to be invoked/interacted with remotely, you would already be  set in the right direction to do so (whereas using native controls would require a migration to a server structure with an HTML/CSS/JS UI in order to be web-enabled).